# Nicer command line parse python

Tags: python, argparse

Using argparse, I have created a small script that contains a command line parser for my analysis program which is part of a self made python package. It works perfectly, but I don't really like how to control it.

This is how the code looks in the script itself

```
def myAnalysis():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='''
        lala''')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--data',help='')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--option_1', help='', default=False, required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--option_2', help='', default=False, required=False)


    # combine parsed arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()code here
```

Additional to this there is some more in the setup file of the analysis package

```
entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
              'py_analysis = edit.__main__:myAnalysis'
          ]
```

As I said, this works without any problems. To analyze some data I have to use

```
py_analysis --data path_to_data_file
```

Sometimes, I need some of the options. For this it may look loke

```
py_analysis --data path_to_data_file --option_1 True --option_2 True
```

In my personal taste, this is kind of ugly. I would prefer something like

```
py_analysis path_to_data_file --option_1 --option_2
```

I am pretty sure this is possible. I just don't know how

Comment: Take a look at the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html. You want `action='store_true'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *store_true* action

```
parser.add_argument('-e', '--option_1', help='', default=False, action ='store_true')
```

Then just adding to command line *--option_1* will set its value to *True*.

Answer (score 1):

To have a positional argument instead of an option, replace:

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--data',help='')
```

by:

```
parser.add_argument('data_file', help='')
```

Comment: Adding _type=argparse.FileType(<access mode>)_ will directly produce file object - instead of string with file name,

Comment: Its a pity, I can't accept two answers, Yours and the one of @volcano combined are exactly what I wanted

Comment: @Glostas no problem ;)